# Condition if/else don't work like expected in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a simple api witch verify if the username and/or password are in the DB and if they are correct.

When I post correct data, it works. When I post a wrong password, it also works. But when I post a wrong username, my condition don't jump to the else. If the username is wrong, it means it is not in the DB. But here, it is like if it was in the DB, but he is not, so I get an error : " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Username') "

Here the code

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    (async () => {
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

    
    try {
        username = req.query.username
        password = req.query.password

        let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
        let hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

        db_conn.getConnection( (err, conn) => {
            
            if(err) throw err;
            
            conn.query("SELECT * FROM mod803_appusers WHERE Username=? ", [username], (err, rows) => {

                //Problem here : when I put a wrong password, it's ok, this condition works because there is a password, and if bcrypt.compare is true, it sends response, but if it's false, it sends 'Wrong password'.
                //But if the Username is Wrong, it means there is no username in the DB. So here, I want this condition jump to the else : 'Incorrect username' but it doesn't.

                if(rows[0]['Username'] && rows[0]['Password']) {
                    bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0]['Password'], function(err, result) {
    
                        if(result){
                            
                            res.send({"table": rows});
    
                        } else {
                            res.send("Wrong password");
    
                    }}); 
                    

                } else {
                    res.send('Incorrect username');

                }
                
            })
            
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
})()

})
```

Thanks

Comment: For security reasons you should not expose the real reason why the credentials are not accepted, just send "Wrong username or password".

Comment: If the query doesn't match anything but there was no error, the callback is called with `null`, `[]`, which means `result` is an empty array and therefore truthy, but `result[0]` is undefined, which is what causes the error. You need `if (result && result[0])` or `if (result.length > 0)` instead. Also note that you can do `result[0].Username`

Comment: ok I understand, thank you it works. Why I can't vote your response ?

And yes, I will show "Wrong username or password" for security.